# Open front camera by default

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-camera, image-capture

I am creating an app, in which I am setting a profile image and cover image ,so on setting profile image I want to open the front camera by default using `intent`.
I am using

```
pictureIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING",1);
```

Its working on Sony but when I tested on a Samsung Galaxy J4 ,it's opening the back camera. I searched and found somewhere that for Samsung one should use value 2.
However it's not working.
I want to do this using intent only.
Does anyone have an idea about it?

Answer (score 2):

You can do like below,

```
private Camera openFrontFacingCamera()  {
   int cameraCount = 0;
  Camera cam = null;
  Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
  cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
   for ( int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++ ) {
      Camera.getCameraInfo( camIdx, cameraInfo );
      if ( cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT  ) {
        try {
            cam = Camera.open( camIdx );
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Camera failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
}

return cam;
}
```

And then use it in your app as follows:

```
public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
  Camera c = null;
  try {
    c = openFrontFacingCamera();
  }
  catch (Exception e){
 }
return c; 

}
```

Comment: After adding this,getting below error in logcat. 
  Camera_APM :: [APM]APM's Thread is started     Camera_APM :: [APM] This app is forground app  Camera: Error 2

Comment: already depricated in a android 13